# MooTools addEvent does not work in IE8 standards mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools

I'm having some issues in having my website work in IE8 standards mode since the addEvent doesn't seem to fire at all. This is the code I have

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<a href="javascript:;" id="add"><img src="img/add.png"/></a>
```

The following JavaScript is ran once the dom is ready:

```js
$('add').addEvent('click',function(){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

This works in IE9 and other browsers but since some of my users are in IE8 (which sucks), I'm trying to get it working there as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any console output? Press F12 and check the `console` tab. Also, which version of MooTools are you using?

Comment: Hi @JonathanSampson There's nothing on the console and I don't see any errors as well. I'm using MooTools 1.4

Comment: I just tested http://jsfiddle.net/HV9km/show/ and it [worked properly](http://i.imgur.com/HvwXACf.png) in IE8. With your console already opened, run your code, and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: Are you using mootools file locally or ajax loading? Where in the page are you loading mootools? How does your page header look like?

Comment: I'm using mootools locally. I'm loading mootools within <head> and the .js file that I have the domready function follows it immediately.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon and Sergio. Your hints helped me figure out the issue. It appeared that addEvent tried to get to the element before it was ready, moved it from domready to onload and it worked (strange).

Comment: @Nash3man, feels strange `domready` didn't work, sounds like a patch to me. Anyway, you can delete this or post more info untill we find the actuall problem. Cheers